# Remove/Hide searchView on only one activity

Tags: java, android

I have 3 activities in my project and I would like to remove/hide the searchView in the actionbar on only one activity.

I tried searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE); but there is still the clickable icon.

main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
      android:title="@string/menu_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/item_clear_memory_cache"
    android:title="@string/menu_item_clear_memory_cache"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/item_clear_disc_cache"
    android:title="@string/menu_item_clear_disc_cache"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).setVisible(false);` should be the way.

Answer (score 6):

You can hide the searchview and the searchicon by doing this:

```
searchItem.setVisible(false);
searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Then you can bring it back by:

```
searchItem.setVisible(true);
searchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some researches here you can find my complete example. Don't forget to set visibility and visible back in activity or fragment where you need to show your search view back.

I was looking a way  to hide search view **in preferences**.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // this means that we're telling the Activity that is hosting the Fragment that we want to display menus
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    /**
     * ********************* SEARCH ********************
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        item.setVisible(false);
        searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

And menu_main.xml

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    />
```